Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration error - Local setup glustack
I am getting the below error when I tried to setup the gluestack-ui locally I have followed the documentation also I am using
yarn version: 1.22.17
node version: v18.17.1
I got the below error after running yarn storybook inside storybook folder
 Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                      resolved symlink to /Users/abishek/gluestack-ui/packages/unstyled/image/index.web.js
                        using description file: /Users/abishek/gluestack-ui/packages/unstyled/image/package.json (relative path: ./index.web.js)
                          no extension
                            Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                            /Users/abishek/gluestack-ui/packages/unstyled/image/index.web.js doesn't exist
                          .web.js


Could you please follow these steps?

Remove node_modules from root as well as from example/storybook folder.
Run yarn inside root folder.
Run yarn build inside root folder.
Run yarn storybook inside example/storybook folder.

Please do let us know if you still face this issue.
